# Term for when you're attributing something to a rule

Tags: syntactic-analysis, terminology

I'm looking for a word or a phase that describes attributing something not to a person or group, but to an inanimate object like a rule.

Ex.

> A best practice is to run cross browser tests in all modern browsers.

instead of

> We test our sites in all modern browsers.

In the first sentence the action of testing is attributed to a rule, not a person. Was curious  if there is a term for when you use passive voice and attribute a recommendation to a rule, best practice, etc. to make it sound more authoritative

Comment: What's wrong with *best practice*? What is the context you want to use this in? Are you looking for a noun, a verb, an adjective, an idiom, a proverb? Please do give us something to work with.

Comment: Edited the question for clarity. Best practice works well, what I'm trying to find a word or phrase for the act of attributing something to an inanimate object. Maybe "inanimate object" is what I'm looking for?

Comment: Major thematic relations ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thematic_relation ): Agent: deliberately performs the action (e.g., Bill ate his soup quietly.). 
...
**Force** or **Natural Cause**: mindlessly performs the action (e.g., An avalanche destroyed the ancient temple.). However, this does not really seem the same as link-verb linked equivalence elements.

Comment: Do you mean writing the sentence in the ***passive*** form instead of in the ***active*** form?

Comment: @TrevorD, I think that helps me clarify the question. So when you use passive voice and attribute a recommendation to a rule, best practice, etc. to make it sound more authoritative is there a term for that?

Comment: Perhaps 'impersonal, professional-sounding' (which of course does _sound_ more authoritative)? It's one of the well-documented reasons for choosing the passive: http://www.monash.edu.au/lls/llonline/grammar/engineering/passive/1.1.xml (reason 4).

Answer (score 0):

This is an *appeal to authority*, used fallaciously as no authority is identified. It's an *unsubstantiated claim*. It's *weasel wording*. As such it might well be an outright *lie*. Fact: a best practice is not to write like that.

There is no passive voice anywhere to be seen in either sentence.

Comment: Thank you and I appreciate the blunt reply. If I added a citation, then it would be an "appeal to authority", correct? As an aside, this is a specific case where the "best practices" described are generally accepted and true. So assuming that what would you suggest when it comes to articulating this as a practical matter?